# Удалить в плагине функцию другого плагина

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! У меня есть платная тема, в ней есть свой плагин. Я хочу немного подредактировать сайт. Через function.php я внёс все правки, всё работает. Сейчас есть цель создать свой плагин и занести в него все правки. Соотвественно я всё это сделал, но столкнулся с проблемой. Я использую функцию remove_action, через которую удаляю функцию, которая прописана в плагине разработчика темы, но этот remove_action не срабатывает.

То есть через function.php всё отлично, а при использовании своего плагина remove_action не удаляет функции которые прописаны в плагине разработчика темы. Как это исправить?

Comment: Удалять хук нужно после того, как он был добавлен. А значит: если вы удаляете хук, а он не удаляется, то скорее всего вы удаляете его до того как он добавляется в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, можно через хук init использовать remove_action чтобы удалить функции другого плагина

```
add_action('init', 'remove_custom_function');

function remove_custom_function(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);

}
```